# How do you change background in activity_main from MainActivity in android sdk?

Tags: android, background

```
package mine.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void changeBackgroundColor(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.color_list);
    }

    public void setBackgroundRed(View view) {
    findViewById(R.layout.activity_main).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

When the app runs it creates a button that runs changeBackgroundColor. It then shows a button that runs setBackgroundRed which crashes the app.

Comment: Ok, assuming this as your mainActivity, & according to your "When the app runs it creates a button that runs changeBackgroundColor"--- Where are you instantiating the Button that needs to call(or run) your changeBackgroundColor(View v) method ?I think you should do in your onCreate();

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your `MainActivity` something like....

```
public void setActivityBackgroundColor(int color) {
    View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

then call this function from your OnClickListener passing in colour whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your onCreate as Following

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.blue);// specify background drawable resource or background color resource here
}
```